# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty ArgumentError in Productcategories#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil
>   or be empty):
>        7:    新增商品分类
>        8: 
>        9: 
>       10:   <%= form_for @productCategories do |f| %> <- 错误在这里 ->
>       11:
>
> 12:     <%= f.label :商品分类名称： %>
>       13:     <%= f.text_field :name %>    app/views/productcategories/new.html.erb:10:in
>   `_app_views_productcategories_new_html_erb__593308190794838703_70267444710660'
>   Rendering
>   /Users/liupengfei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb
>   within rescues/layout   Rendering
>   /Users/liupengfei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>   Rendered
>   /Users/liupengfei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
>   (4.1ms)   Rendering
>   /Users/liupengfei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb   Rendered
>   /Users/liupengfei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.1ms)   Rendering
>   /Users/liupengfei/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb

And this is my source code:

```
def new
  @productCategory = ProductCategory.new
end

def create
  @productCategory = ProductCategory.new(ProductCategory_params)

  if @ProductCategory.save
    redirect_to productcategories_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Please, help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong instance variable name in the form

```
def new
  @productCategory = ProductCategory.new
end
```

Change

```
<%= form_for @productCategories do |f| %> <- 错误在这里 ->
```

to

```
<%= form_for @productCategory do |f| %> <- 错误在这里 ->
```

**EDIT:**

For the error you are getting you need to pass the path manually

```
<%= form_for @productCategory, url: productcategories_path do |f| %> <- 错误在这里 ->
```

Comment: NoMethodError in Productcategories#new
Showing /Users/liupengfei/我的项目/我的毕设/scht/app/views/productcategories/new.html.erb where line #10 raised:

undefined method `product_categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc10ce0710>:0x007fbc18140f10>
Did you mean?  productcategories_path
               productcategory_path
               products_path
               productcategories_url
Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
13
              
</div>
<div class="row">
  <%= form_for @productCategory do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :商品分类名称： %>
    <%= f.text_field